# Regex: Select and Delete all content of file, except "DATE" format

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I have a file with many dates in the format of `03/07/2017`.

For exemple:

> My lovely letter can't be read...
>
> academicsdirectbu.tps 10.7 k  `03/07/2017` 11:39  -a--
>
> bash: remove all files except last version in file name `02/04/2015` before Table

So, I want to match and delete all content except Date format. First I made a regex to find all Dates:

`\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4}`

And I include this into another regex `\b(?!(\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4}))[\w-]+\b`

But, my second regex, which has to select and Delete all content of file, except "DATE", doesn't work too good.

Can anyone help me a little bit? So, my desire output should be:

`03/07/2017`

`02/04/2015`

Comment: What do you want to get in the end?

Comment: hello Wiktor. I edit my question. In the end I want to remain in files only those 2 dates:  `03/07/2017` and `02/04/2015`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**: `(\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4})|.`
**Replace With**: `(?{1}$1\n:)`
**`.` matches newline**: *On*

Note: You may also add word boundaries around the date pattern to make it a bit more precise, `\b(\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4})\b|.`.

Now, `(\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,4})` will match and capture the date into Group 1 and if not found at the current location, `.` will match any char there. In the replacement pattern, the date is replaced with itself and a newline is added after it, and if Group 1 is not matched, the char is just removed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Wiktor. Works even without .match newline ;)